# Azure Cognitive Search : Filter by document size

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

is that possible to search the documents by size in Azure Cognitive search?How?

Swati

Answer (score 1):

You can Filter in the Customize target index,

at the metadata_storage_size, you can check filterable.

As screenshot shown.

[image]

Hope its can help you.